# SimpleTagSupport cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm studying `JSTL`. I'm following a simple example found on the internet.
I created a Class that extended `SimpleTagSupport`. But i get this error

```
  SimpleTagSupport cannot be resolved to a type
```

I have `Tomcat 7`, `Java 1.7` System Library and i added as external jars `'servlet-api.jar'`

What did i miss?
Thank you

Comment: Have you added jstl jar? If so, post your code or share the link.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that find this question, another possible problem is caused by your eclipse .classpath file. I needed to change this:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.macosx.MacOSXType/Java SE 7 [1.7.0_51]">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

to this:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
```